# Can WordFrequencyData be used with phrases?

Tags: curated-data, linguistics

Can [`WordFrequencyData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WordFrequencyData.html) be used with phrases?  I'd like to look up words/phrases like "cell phone" instead of "cellphone".

```
WordFrequencyData[{"cellphone", "cell phone"}, {"TimeSeries"}, All, IgnoreCase -> False]
```

Google's Ngram viewer allows this, so the data exists.  I read through the documentation and didn't see anything.

[Example](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cellphone%2Ccell+phone&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ccellphone%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcellphone%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCellphone%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCellPhone%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCELLPHONE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccell%20phone%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcell%20phone%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCell%20phone%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCell%20Phone%3B%2Cc0) from Google Books Ngram viewer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) of [`WordFrequencyDaya`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WordFrequencyDaya.html) it's working through this:

```
System`WordFrequencyDump`Private`iWolframAlphaAPICompute[\
WordFrequencyData, "MWAWordFrequency", {arg1, "Year" -> date, 
  IgnoreCase -> caseoption, "IncludeCaseVariants" -> casevariants, 
  "IncludePOSVariants" -> posvariants, 
  "SourceCorpus" -> sourcecorpus}]
```

Where the relevant parameter is `"SourceCorpus"` which happens to just be any member of this list:

```
System`WordFrequencyDump`Private`$WordFrequencyValidLanguages

{"english", "hebrew", "italian", "german", "french", "spanish", \
"russian", "chinese"}
```

And so it just passes that up to WolframAlpha to compute, so let's try this test case: [Frequency of phrase cell phone in English](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Frequency+of+phrase+cell+phone+in+english)

And it fails to compute that, so this function likely can't handle that case. Note that it is possible to compute this: [Frequency of word cellphone in English](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Frequency+of+word+cellphone+in+english) so it's not just that the query is bad.

On the other hand, if you have a decent corpus you could do the first part of [what this guy did](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1136952). Or, alternatively, you can just [use google's data](http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html) (see, for instance, the NOUN 2-grams).